# How to cancel the browser XHR multiple callback queue when client redirects?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

Please can anybody suggest what might have been wrong in the following scenario?

When a page loads there are e.g. 5 async calls being made to the server. 
The first call fails and sends error code to the browser.

The javascript code upon failure tries redirect to login page and makes a redirect call, however all the previous 4 calls responses are first handled before the javascript redirection call.

My guess is redirection call is in last of the browser callback queue and hence gets handled when all other previous calls response (which are error responses) were made.

Now, I do not want to show the error message box 4 times before user is redirected to login page.

Is there any workaround for the issue? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: _If_ the page is really redirected, the XHR cancels itself. What you can do, is to order the async calls so, that the first call is the one which redirects, and in the case redirection is not needed, it calls the other XHRs.

Comment: what do you mean by "The browser/javascript decides to redirect and makes a redirect call"

Comment: @Teemu "If the page is really redirected, the XHR cancels itself." please can you elaborate? you mean after the redirect happens right? but my problem is redirection is still in the queue

Comment: The unload process of the current page will cancel the pending AJAX calls. And there's also a suggestion of what you can do to avoid your problem in my comment.